# How To Correctly Add Print Support To FullCalendar.IO

Tags: javascript, html, printing, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a premium version of this product, I am using the generic code they post on the site for this example.  I have this code, which appears to be the correct way to implement the adaptive plugin, but I do not see a way to print the calendar?

What am I missing here?

````
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "index.php?option=com_ajax&plugin=getEmpData&format=json&ser="+ser+"&m_id="+m_id+"&formid="+formid+"&fdate="+fdate+"&tdate="+tdate,
    success: function(data)
    {
      if (!data.data['0']) {
        jQuery("#print-btn").hide();
        jQuery("#geted-bschart").html('');
        jQuery("#geted-results").html('No Data exist');
      } else {
        jQuery("#geted-results").html("");
        const getEmpData = JSON.parse(data.data['0']);

        let bs = getEmpData['0'];
        getEmpData.shift();
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('geted-results');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
          views: { 
        dayGridMonth: {
                    type: 'dayGrid',
                    duration: { months: mths },
                    monthMode: true,
                    fixedWeekCount: false,
                }
          },
          plugins: [
              adaptivePlugin
          ],
          headerToolbar: {
              left:   '',
              center: 'title',
              right:  ''
          },
          initialDate: fdtArray['2']+'-'+fdtArray['0']+'-'+fdtArray['1'],
          editable: false,
          selectable: true,
          businessHours: true,
          dayMaxEvents: true,
          events: getEmpData
        });

        jQuery("#geted-bschart").html(bs.calc);
        calendar.render();
        jQuery("#print-btn").show();
        if (jQuery( ".res-legends" ) && jQuery( ".res-legends" ).length) {
          jQuery(".res-legends").remove();
        }
        jQuery(lhtml).insertAfter(".fc-header-toolbar");
      }
      jQuery('#getEmpDataForm input, #getEmpDataForm button').prop('disabled', false);
    },
    error(xhr,status,error,data)
    {
      jQuery('#getEmpDataForm input, #getEmpDataForm button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
 });```
````

Comment: To print the calendar you can just use your browser's standard print feature. If you loaded fullCalendar's CSS correctly in your page then it already comes with print media queries to adapt the output to print format. As far as I can see, the adaptive plugin just makes a better job of it than the default non-premium functionality. Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: @ADyson - i have a customization using this in which I allow a manager to select an employee, and select a start date and end date, and press a button.  Then a query is run, and a '<div>' tag is displayed and the results are populated on fullcalendar.  In doing it this way, if I use the browsers print feature, the calendar is not displayed in the print.

Comment: I see. You'll need to provide us with a [mre] of that issue then, before we can really help you with it.

Comment: @ADyson - see if my edit with additional code provides what is needed?